# Cannot connect to IP using sockets

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to connect to my public IP address but to no success.

The port is open as checked using - http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
and a request from this site (http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) works.

My problem is with this PHP code below. This used to work fine when used on my local network. Now I am using it on a web server.

Could the problem be with the web server to allowing the request to be sent or am I doing something wrong?

```
$ip = "MYIP";
$port = "600";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//socket_bind($sock, $ip, $port) or die ("cannot bind to address."); 
echo($ip); 
$state = socket_connect($sock,$ip, $port);
$error = socket_last_error();
$errorMsg = socket_strerror($error);
echo($errorMsg);
```

EDIT : The error in my comment below was derived with the socket_bind commented (Code edited to output the error)

Error : Connection timed out

Comment: Extend your code with socket_last_error(), http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php and provide the error, without that it's difficult to see what's wrong.

Comment: When converted using socket_strerror() the message is "Connection timed out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
socket_bind($sock, $ip, $port) or ...
$state = socket_connect($sock,$ip, $port);
```

Bind binds the local address of the socket, it doesn't make sense to bind and connect to the same port. In general you do not want to bind in client mode. Remove the line completely, then you may get real error.

Comment: HI, Please check my edit. The error mentioned in my comment was derived with the socket_bind commented. Thanks on description of what socket_bind actually does as I saw it in an example and thought I try it.

Comment: Then in that case you're not able to connect to this server on that port from the web server. Is the port correct, i.e. in rexswain you specify yourhos:600/... ? It could be also the case that the communication is blocked by firewall on webhosting, especially being the case for public hostings...

Comment: Yes the port is correct, in rexswain is specify the same ip and port and I can see the request on my microcontroller, but from the webserver the request to same ip and port is being timed out. Yes it could be the case that the communication is blocked by firewall as Im using a shared web hosting. The same code used to work on my web server but it was on my local network.

Comment: Well, so most probably it's firewall. Webhosting usually limits the communication so the users cannot abuse or attack others.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Contacted them and they opened the outgoing port right away. Worked fine afterwards :)